# modifying vector at same iterator

Tags: c++, oop, iterator, std-pair, push-back

Suppose i have the following vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair <int, bool> > myV;
std::vector<std::pair <int, bool> >::iterator it;
```

And then i initialize them for 10 row:

```
 for (i = 0 ; i < 10; i++){
           if (i % 2 == 0 )
                j = true;
            else 
                j = false
           myV.push_back(std::make_pair(i,j));
  } //end of for
```

Now , i need to modify my vector at node 5, or each node, one way is : i get backup from it, and `erase` it, and then `push_back`, But for a specific reason , i need to keep order of my `vector`, do you have any idea?

Comment: What on earth does `cevtor` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vectors give random access; you can simply reassign the element:

```
myV[5] = std::make_pair(42, true);
*it = std::make_pair(35, false);
```